# Automatically trigger a macro whenever certain file is saved in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find out what could possibly trigger a macro to run everytime my colleague saved a file into the shared drive.

"xxx Report.xlsx" is saved into the shared folder monthly, and the data inside are re-organized with additional spreadsheets automatically. I found the macro which did the re-organizing/amendment but I don't really understand what could trigger the macro to run.

I don't think it's under task scheduler because the person who wrote the macro left and the macro is still running...

Any advice, please? Thanks!

```
Sub OrganiseTimesheetReport()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Renaming Original Report
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Original Report"

   'Safekeeping the original report - Duplicating the worksheet for further working
    ActiveSheet.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

   'Renaming Organised Report
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Organised Report"

   'Deleting Top Information & Empty Row Between Header and Content & Last Grand Total Row
    Dim HeaderInfoDelete As Range

    Set HeaderInfoDelete = Range("B1", "B" & Rows.Count).Find(What:="Calculated total records", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not HeaderInfoDelete Is Nothing Then
      If HeaderInfoDelete.Row > 1 Then Range("B1:B" & HeaderInfoDelete.Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

   'Deleting Unnecessary Columns & Rows
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, col As Long, LRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For LRow = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Trim(Cells(LRow, 5)) = "" Then
        Rows(LRow).Delete
        End If
    Next LRow

    Range("B1").Copy
    Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("B1").ClearContents

    For col = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        If Trim(Cells(1, col)) = "" Then
        Columns(col).Delete
        End If
    Next col

    Dim ReLastRow As Long, ReLRow As Long

    ReLastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For ReLRow = ReLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Trim(Cells(ReLRow, 1)) = "" Then
        Rows(ReLRow).Delete
        End If
    Next ReLRow

 ' Pasting the Header

    Set Cwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Mwb = ThisWorkbook

        Mwb.Sheets("Report Templates").Rows("1:1").Copy
        Cwb.Sheets("Organised Report").Rows("1:1").Insert
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

 ' Converting DateTime Format
    Dim col As Integer
    For col = 6 To 9

    With Sheets("Organised Report").UsedRange.Columns(col).Cells
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
    End With

    Next col

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: How time sensitive is this?  Do seconds matter? hours?  Also, what does the macro *do*?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a copy of the code so we can help you understand what it does.

Comment: @girlvsdata, I included a portion of the code to show what it does because the entire code is too long. The macro does formatting and including new spreadsheets & new fields. I could understand this macro but I couldn't understand how was the macro triggered to run. Thanks!

Comment: @ashleedawg, the document is not time sensitive but I think it ran everytime, the file was downloaded and saved in the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking in the task scheduler then either:

- I really don't understand what you're trying to do *or*
- You are trying to be doing something you've never done before.

**If it's the former** - happens to me all the time

**If it's the latter** - happens to me all the time too.... doing something for the first time is fun!

---

The behavior you experienced is a typical use case for VBA automation and it is usually triggered by a specific see of conditions.  A classic example is the generation and distribution of the Balance Sheet and Profit & Loss reports. VBA may be triggered to run if the current date is within a specific window and certain fields have been updated.  For example, if it is after the 1st of the month but before the 7th, data for the previous month exists, and the the program has not run yet ... then it may be set to run automatically.  Furthermore, it may be 'polite' and  wait until you save or try to close the workbook and use that event as the trigger.

If you didn't understand that, don't worry, finding out is easy!

To avoid possible confusion, make sure you don't have another spreadsheet or Excel window open.  Then go ahead and open the spreadsheet:

- Press  Alt and f11 at the same time to open the VBA editor
- A new window should open and you should see a project explorer on the left side of the screen with expandable/collapsible tree (usually titled 'myproject')
- Expand the project tree and double click on "workbook".  finding it is slightly different between versions of excel and you may have to expand a folder or two before you see it.  it's also possible it could have been renamed but unlikely.
- After you've double clicked, the center of the screen  *should* be showing any VBA code triggered by workbook events.  if there's a lot of text, `ctrl+f` to open the find box and search for the word "save".
- Look for something starting like

  ```
  private sub workbook_BeforeSave()
  ```

---

If you can't find anything relevant there then there could be  a custom event handler in a class module - In which case, my advice would be to make a backup copy of the spreadsheet as a precaution and then look around and try to figure out what reach program does. You may have found a great resource that will help solve common problems or automate your workflow.

I probably should have mentioned this first... if this file is a Macro-enabled Workbook then these steps are very likely to land you where I think you want to be.

Comment: I tried to look for any codes under workbook but nope, nothing is there. The workbook with the macro has it under a module, there is nothing under the "Sheet1" or "ThisWorkbook". After some research googling, I think it might be some external handler or WMI, etc which I have no idea how those work.

Comment: for good measure, you may want to go back one more time to use ctrl f and to search for "save" with the radio button set to check the entire project, not be case sensitive, and not check the whole word.  being vba, the code can reside in other office apps like outlook word, powerpoint,  etc. if you didn't have any other excel files open and there were other projects then you might want to check those.  also, take a look at the shortcut used to launch the application. it may have extra parameters or point to a script and somewhere else.

Comment: i don't know what your final objective is. if it's too stop the behavior or learn from it. stopping it can be done several ways with out finding itour have to find it the lesson. 
it occurred to me that it may not be "event" driven, if your typical accountant type created it then it will be in the module you found likely triggered by the the date going to a new month or a change to a cell or worksheet.  sounds like balance sheet / p&l automation but i come from that works do everything looks like a dollar sign to be.